# How to determine if the team project is TFVC OR GIT

Tags: tfs, tfvc

We can create a project in TFS (Team Foundation Server) choosing version control - Git or TFVC. But how can I check from a existing project that which version control it uses? I saw a similar thread in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f917f82-36b2-4a58-b364-185bfe0aff79/how-to-determine-if-the-team-project-is-tfvc-or-git?forum=tfsgeneral which says to connect the projects using TFVC APIs - if it fails the project using Git, if succeed it is using TFVC.

But, I dont want to write piece of client code to determine it. Can we not check if from the web console of the TFS server?
The TFS server we have is 2010.

Comment: But tfs 2010 does not support GIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

TFS 2010 doesn't have Git support, so any version control you're using is TFVC.

Beyond that: Modern versions of TFS (2015 onward) don't have Git- or TFVC-specific team projects; any team project can host a TFVC repo, any number of Git repos, or both.